# assign result and status code from wget to variables

Tags: wget, stdout, stderr

Can I get the response and status code and assign them to variables?

```
# wget https://www.google.com --quiet --server-response 1> >(body=$(</dev/stdin)) 2> >(grep HTTP | awk '{print $2}' | statusCode=$(</dev/stdin) )
# echo $body

# echo $statusCode

#
```

(I can't; maybe you can?)